# Write a value with OPC UA Java (OPC Foundation)

Tags: java, simulation, opc, scada, opc-ua

I am trying to connect to a remote environment using the OPC UA java stack from the OPC Foundation. Reading values is working correct, for that I am using the following code:

```
NodeId nodeId= NodeId.get(IdType.String, 2, "TYPES!M!MULTIPLYER!MU_79.MULTIPLYER_BIAS");
ReadResponse res = mySessionChannel.Read(null, 500.0, TimestampsToReturn.Source, new ReadValueId(nodeId, Attributes.Value, null, null));
```

Now I am trying to use the write command to set this (input) variable as follows:

```
NodeId nodeId = NodeId.get(IdType.String, 2, "TYPES!M!MULTIPLYER!MU_79.MULTIPLYER_BIAS");
DataValue dataValue = new DataValue(new Variant(999));
WriteValue writeValue[] = new WriteValue[1];
writeValue[0] = new WriteValue(nodeId, Attributes.Value, "0", dataValue);

RequestHeader requestHeader = new RequestHeader(nodeId, null, null, null, null, null, null);
WriteRequest writeRequest = new WriteRequest(requestHeader, writeValue);
WriteResponse response = mySessionChannel.Write(writeRequest);
```

The write command runs without errors but the value never changes. 
Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining "0" as IndexRange (3rd param of WriteValue). I believe, you have a scalar variable, so you should just use null, instead.

Also you need to check the response to actually see if it succeeds or not.

E: The write parameter must match the DataType of the Variable node.

Comment: I changed it to null, the value isnt changing and the response is:WriteResponse (id=1474131049)
  ResponseHeader=ResponseHeader (id=676105376)
    ServiceDiagnostics=DiagnosticInfo (id=967078155)
      localizedText=null
      locale=null
      innerDiagnosticInfo=null
      symbolicId=null
      innerStatusCode=null
      additionalInfo=null
      stringTable=null
      stringArray=class java.lang.String[0]
      namespaceUri=null
    StringTable=class java.lang.String[0]

Comment: RequestHandle=UnsignedInteger (id=1526310589)
      value=1
    Timestamp=DateTime (id=1925333515)
      value=130393207472672000
    AdditionalHeader=null
    ServiceResult=StatusCode (id=2163771)
      value=0
  DiagnosticInfos=class org.opcfoundation.ua.builtintypes.DiagnosticInfo[0]
  Results=class org.opcfoundation.ua.builtintypes.StatusCode[1]
    [0]=StatusCode (id=2006760845)
    value=-2139881472

Comment: It's better to print the StatusCodes as string: it will tell you the actual code, e.g. response.getResults()[0]

Comment: This indeed makes more sense to me: Bad_TypeMismatch (0x80740000) "The value supplied for the attribute is not of the same type as the attribute's value." Now see how I can fix this.

Comment: You need to find the DataType of the node you are writing to and provide a respective value. UA does not allow the server to convert data types automatically.